# Retrive the list with all price of AWS of all regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, price

So is there any way to get a list (csv, excel, whatever) that lists all price for AWS?

E.g.:

```
Region         | type      | price
north virgina    m3.large    0.12$
london           m3.large    0.17$
london           s3          0.55$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve this information using the [PriceListAPI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/).

There is a service listing the prices for each region e.g. https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json (this list is large and you need to parse/extract it). There a links for each of the services.